# Access Query How to Merge Two Fields Into One

Tags: microsoft-access

I'm working with two tables in a simple database.  The data on each table contains partial data that together would comprise a completed record.  I'd like to merge the two tables with a query and combine some of the fields to display in a single query.  Let's say Table A [PhoneNum] and Table B [PhoneNum] fields exist.  In order to display a complete record I need to combine [PhoneNum] from both tables into one in the query results.

Is this possible to do in a query?  I believe the answer lies within SQL, but I have never touched SQL and am not sure how to implement.

Comment: What do you mean by combine? Also what have you tried already? Some sample data might help too.

Answer (score 1):

If you work on database tasks longer than a day, I would suggest to go through the [SQL Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_intro.asp) first and learn it. It's not very complex language to learn and it might help you in future as well.

For your task have a specific look on **UNION**.

I think the answer should be like this, if I understand you correctly.

```sql
SELECT PhoneNum FROM Table_A
UNION
SELECT PhoneNum FROM Table_B
```